# Flutter griview on card

Tags: flutter, user-experience

I would like to ask if somebody knows how to remove offset on top of gridview in #flutter, looks like gridview doesn't match parent height [screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8VQCG.jpg)

```html
Widget _buildGridView({BuildContext context, List<TileWidget> children}) {
    return Card(
      margin: padding(context),
      borderOnForeground: true,
      color: Colors.black45,
      semanticContainer: true,
      clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
      child: GridView.count(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
        crossAxisCount: sqrt(children.length).toInt(),
        children: children
      ),
      elevation: 5,
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Could you please share the code you tried

Comment: sorry forgotten sample, just edited post